# How do I setState of a row from a different JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have made reactjs app with electron. On the app, there is a table(table.js) on one of the pages that have columns that are all apart of the state. I am rendering all components through the main file App.js. But I have a nodejs script that follows through with some requests. As the script goes on I want to update the state of one of the columns per row in table.js. How can I achieve this?

Table.js:

```
 <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {rows.map((row,i) => {
                return(
                    <tr>
                        <td>{i}</td>
                        <td>{task.task.Number}</td>
                        <td>{task.task.Place}</td>
                        <td>{row.row.Status}</td>
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is the nodejs script (example):

```
request.get(url, (err, resp, body) => {
  *here is where I want to set the State of the status(col3) in Table.js*
})
```

In App.js this gives an example of my constructor:

```
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
  render:'',
  row: {
    Number: '',
    Place: '',
    Status: '',
  },

  rows: []
}
```

}

Keep in mind all files are in the src folder of the react-app.

Comment: Your request is going to need to need to change the `row.Status` state in your App.js. Changing the state will trickle down to the table component.

Comment: @skylerfenn How would you say I go about coding this. I understand what you mean but not fully. How do I achieve this if my request is in a different file?

Comment: Where are you calling the request?

Comment: @skylerfenn In the nodejs script shown in the example above. The nodejs script example itself is a different file.

Comment: Well, you can import the request into your App.js and use it there. You can use the data from the response and update your state there.

Comment: @skylerfenn can you make this an answer I believe this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to import the request into your App.js and use it there. You can use the data from the response and update your state there.

For example, in the code below, you could use the `getRow` method to update the state:

```
import request from 'request-library';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          render: '',
          row: {
            Number: '',
            Place: '',
            Status: '',
          },
          rows: []
        }; 
    }

    getRow = async (rowToGet) => {
        const response = await request.get(rowToGet);
        this.setState({
            rows: this.state.rows.map((row) => {
                if (newRow.Number === row.Number) {
                    row.Status = newRow.Status;
                }
                return row;
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        <Table rows={this.state.rows} />
    }
}
```